# Finding pairs with smallest XOR values from a list

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

I am working on a problem in which I am expected to take the xor of
all the pair of integers in an array and then find the K smallest
integers produced from xor'ing. The size of the array can be N=100000 
and so K can be quite large but its limited to 250000.

For example,
if N=5 and K=4,

our array is `{1 3 2 4 2}`

The numbers resulting from xoring(1 and 3, 1-2, 1-4, 1-2, 3-2, 3-4, 3-2 etc)

```
3 3 2 5 0 1 6 1 6 7
```

Since K=4, we have to print 4 smallest integers.
so the answer would be 0 1 1 2.

Since the time limit is 2 sec and very tight, using the brute force approach
of xoring all the numbers would time out. My approach was wrong and so I need
help. May be we can exploit the limit on K=250000 and want to know if it is 
possible to get the K smallest numbers without xoring all the integers.

Comment: OK, this is really bothering me. All the ideas provided so far can still mean you go over all the possible pairs in some extreme cases. The '2 second' limit is kind of arbitrary, because it is affected by the hardware, etc... What hardware are we talking about? Which CPU? How much memory, etc... ?

Comment: Also what is the range of the numbers? Are we talking about 32 bit numbers? 16 bit numbers (that would be a lot easier...)? All non-negative numbers?

Comment: All are non-negative 32 bit numbers and expected to run on a normal PC. The limit on K is min(250000, N*(N-1)/2).

Comment: Any limitation on the computer language?

Comment: No! But I will prefer C/C++ or python.

Comment: There's now way you can do this in Python. Can we assume a 64-bit process, 8GB of RAM and a 4-core CPU?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
(x ^ y) == (x | y) - (x & y) >= |y - x|
```

Sorting your numbers in order would be a start, because the difference between the pairs will give you a lower bound for the xor, and therefore a cutoff point for when to stop looking for numbers to xor x with.

There is also a shortcut to looking for pairs of numbers whose xor is less than (say) a power of 2, because you're only interested in x <= y <= x | (2 ^ N - 1). If this doesn't give you enough pairs, increase N and try again.

EDIT: You can of course exclude the pairs of numbers that you already found whose xor is less than the previous power of 2, by using x | (2 ^ (N - 1) - 1) < y <= x | (2 ^ N) - 1.

Example based on (sorted) [1, 2, 2, 3, 4]

Start by looking for pairs of numbers whose xor is less than 1: for each number x, search for subsequent numbers y = x. This gives {2, 2}.

If you need more than one pair, look for pairs of numbers whose xor is less than 2 but not less than 1: for each number x, search for numbers x < y <= x | 1. This gives {2, 3} (twice).

Note that the final xor values aren't quite sorted, but each batch is strictly less than the previous batch.

If you need more than that, look for pairs of numbers whose xor is less than 4 but not less than 2: for each number x, search for numbers x | 1 < y <= x | 3. This gives {1, 2} (twice); {1, 3}.

If you need more than that, look for pairs of numbers whose xor is less than 8 but not less than 4: for each number x, search for numbers x | 3 < y <= x | 7. This gives {1, 4}; {2, 4} (twice); {3, 4}.

Comment: Instead of sorting by value, sorting by Gray Code (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gray_code) is a better option.

Comment: I'm not sure why. If two numbers differ by just 1 bit, it can still be the MSB, and their XOR will be rather large.

Comment: @Neil: Can you explain your approach to me with an example?

Answer (score 4):

Notice that if the all bits to the left of `bit n` (counting from the right) of numbers `x` and `y` are equal, `x xor y` ≤ 2<sup>n</sup>-1

```
x = 0000000000100110
y = 0000000000110010
               ^Everything to the left of bit 5 is equal
                so x xor y ≤ 25-1 = 31
```

This can be exploited by storing every number in a [bitwise-trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie#Bitwise_tries) - that is, a trie where every edge is either a `0` or a `1`.  Then `x xor y` ≤ 2<sup>d(x,y)</sup>-1, where `d(x,y)` is the number of steps we need to move up to find the least-common ancestor of `x` and `y`.

```
                             root
                        (left-most bit)
                              0
                             /
                            0
                           /
                          ...
                          1
                         / \
                        0   1
                       /   /
                      0   0
                    ... ...
                    /   /
                   0   0
                   x   y

x and y share an ancestor-node that is 5 levels up, so d(x,y) is 5
```

Once you have the trie, it's easy to find all pairs such that `d(x,y) = 1` - just navigate to all nodes 1 level above the leaves, and compare each of that node's children to each other.  Those values will give you a max `x xor y` of 2<sup>1</sup>-1 = 1.

If you still don't have `k` values, then move up to all nodes 2 levels above the leaves, and compare each of that node's grandchildren to each other<sup>†</sup>.  Those values will give you a max `x xor y` of 2<sup>2</sup>-1 = 3.

<sup>†</sup> *(Actually, you only need to compare each of the leaves in the left-subtree with each of the leaves in the right-subtree, since each of the leaves in a given subtree have already been compared against each other)*

Continue this until, after checking all nodes for a given level, you have at least `k` values of `x xor y`.  Then sort that list of values, and take the `k` smallest.

---

When `k` is small (<< n<sup>2</sup>), this algorithm is **O(n)**.  For large `k`, it is **O(2<sup>b</sup>n)**, where **b** is the number of bits per integer *(assuming there are not many duplicates)*.

Answer (score 0):

I would approach this by first sorting the input array of integers. Then, the pairs with the smallest xor values will be next to each other (but not all adjacent pairs will have the smallest xor values). You can start with adjacent pairs, then work outwards, checking pairs (N, N+2), (N, N+3), until you have reached your desired list of K smallest results.

For your sample array `{1 3 2 4 2}`, the sorted array is `{1 2 2 3 4}` and the pairwise xor values are:

```
1 xor 2 = 3
2 xor 2 = 0
2 xor 3 = 1
3 xor 4 = 7
```

For the next step,

```
1 xor 2 = 3
2 xor 3 = 1
2 xor 4 = 6
```

and again,

```
1 xor 3 = 2
2 xor 4 = 6
```

finally,

```
1 xor 4 = 5
```

This idea isn't complete, but you should be able to use it to help construct a full solution.

Comment: I'm not sure that a-b < c-d guarantees that a^b < c^d . I'll need to think of a counter-example.

Comment: (All in hex) 10, 0F and 10, 0E. 10-0F = 1 < 10-0E = 2, but 1F > 1E. Your heuristic will get a good estimate of the result, but the last elements on your result will not be accurate.

Comment: Yes, examples like `3 xor 4 = 7` show that adjacency doesn't imply a low xor result. However, as Neil mentioned somewhat more succinctly, `|x - y|` is a lower bound on `x ^ y`, which will be helpful in solving this problem.

Comment: @zmbq 25-5<25-2 but 25^5>25^2.